# How to make a discord money bot

Tags: discord, bots

So, I wanted to make a discord bot, where you can play with ingame-money, and can buy things with it. But the problem is, I have the money saved in a variable, so **every** player has the same money then, when **anyone** on the server modifies it. My question now is, how to make a variable for every player, that they have their own money, and no one else has acces to it.
(I am sorry if there are some grammar mistakes, I am not really good at english)

Comment: What is the code that you have tried so far?

Comment: `let bankmoney = 0;
let money = 0;`

Comment: the rest is just if your money is too less or too much he sends a message

Answer (score 0):

You need a structure to store user data in. If its just for one server I would use a JSON (python dict) to store in. If you are planning on using this bot in multiple servers or a very large server I would use a database such as SQLite.